# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable in loss.backward()

Tags: python, pytorch

While trying to set up a pytorch model, I am getting the error that the loss object is not callable when trying to do Pytorch autograd. (Relevant code shown below)

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr, 
  betas(0.0,0.9))

def train(epoch, shuffle, wisdom_model, optim, loss):
    print('train')
    accuracy = 0
    batch_num = 0
    wisdom_model.train()
    for batch in data.train_dl:

        optim.zero_grad()

        result = model(batch[0])
        loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(result, batch[1].long())

        loss.backward()

        accuracy += accuracy(result, batch[1])
        print(accuracy)
        pdb.set_trace()
        batch_num += 1

    return accuracy / batch_num
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-5b9c9fe3b320> in <module>
----> 1 run(1, False)

<ipython-input-27-d0d67dbf6eb2> in run(num_models, dropout)
     71 
     72     for epoch in range(10):
---> 73         train_accuracy = train(epoch, False, model, optimizer, loss)
     74         accuracy.append(validate(epoch, model))
     75 

<ipython-input-27-d0d67dbf6eb2> in train(epoch, shuffle, model, optim, loss)
     24         pdb.set_trace()
     25 
---> 26         loss.backward()
     27         optim.step()
     28 

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: The error isn't that the `loss` is not callable, but that `loss.backward` is an `int` and therefore not callable. Looking at a few examples from the `pytorch` [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=cross%20entropy%20loss#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss), I don't see `loss.backward()` with this specific loss (`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`)...

Comment: Make sure that the code you have given above is the same code as the error stack trace is from. I do not see `optim.step()` after `backward()` call in the code, but stack trace does show so.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(result, batch[1].long())
```

Check out the [nn.CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=nn%20crossentropyloss#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss).

Should not look like this:

```
nn.CrossEntropyLoss()()
```

Should look like this:

```
nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with the datatype of your target i.e. batch[1]. Check if it is of type Tensor(). A simple torch.tensor(batch[1]) will do the job.